# NullpointerException when trying to addFooterView() in Activity

Tags: java, android

I've been looking around for similar problem but I couldn't find anything that made me wiser, excuse me if i failed in my research.

**Problem:** I'm trying to add a footer with a button inside a activity that shows a **ExpandableListView**. If someone can point out what i'm doing wrong that would be awesome!

***Here is my activity code*:**

```
public class QuestionActivityMek extends ExpandableListActivity {


//private static final String LOG_TAG = "QuestionActivity2";
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
//HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mek_list_layout);
    ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    groupNames.add("1. TÄNK IGENOM UPPDRAGET");
    groupNames.add("2. IDENTIFIERA FAROR I UPPDRAGET");


    ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> questions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>>();
    ArrayList<Question> question = new ArrayList<Question>();
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig vad uppdraget innebär?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig hur jag tar mig till arbetsplatsen säkert?", false));
    question.add (new Question("Har jag klart för mig vilka arbetsmoment som ingår i uppdraget?", false));
    questions.add(question);
    question = new ArrayList<Question>();
    question.add(new Question("Riskerar jag inte att snubbla/halka/falla? Check underlag,skyddsräcken, trappor, trappsteg och arbetsplatformar", true));
    question.add (new Question("Finns ingen påkörningsrisk, travers eller truck?", true));
    questions.add(question);
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter (this, groupNames, questions);

    //<<<<<Trying to add a button in the footer under the ExpandableListView>>>>>>
    final Button btnAddMore = new Button(this);
    btnAddMore.setText("continue");
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
    expListView.addFooterView(btnAddMore);
    //<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>

    setListAdapter (listAdapter);


}
```

***LogCat error:***

```
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ovakoappen/com.example.ovakoappen.QuestionActivityMek}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at com.example.ovakoappen.QuestionActivityMek.onCreate(QuestionActivityMek.java:69)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5267)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-04 19:15:12.795: E/AndroidRuntime(31621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
```

***My ExpandableListAdapter:***

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private QuestionActivityMek context;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> listDataChild;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private boolean indicator;
//int previousGroup = -1;


public ExpandableListAdapter(QuestionActivityMek context, List<String> listDataHeader,
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Question>> listChildData) {
this.context = context;
this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
this.listDataChild = listChildData;
inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return listDataChild.get( groupPosition ).get( childPosition );
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;

if( convertView != null ) {
    view = convertView;
}
// else 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false); 
Question question = (Question)getChild( groupPosition, childPosition );
TextView txtviewquestion = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.question );
//ExpandableListView explistview =  (ExpandableListView)view.findViewById(R.layout.mek_list_layout);

Button btnPos = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPositive);
Button btnNeg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNegative);

if( txtviewquestion != null )
    txtviewquestion.setText(question.getQuestion());
    indicator = question.getIndicator();

    btnPos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //if (indicator){

            //context.showRiskEvaluationDialog();


            //} else 

                Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    btnNeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //if (indicator){
                context.showRiskEvaluationDialog();
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            //} else 


        }


    });

return view;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
return listDataChild.get( groupPosition ).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = null;
//String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

if (convertView != null) {
    view = convertView;
} else
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, parent, false);
String getgroup = (String)getGroup (groupPosition);
TextView questiongroup = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
ExpandableListView explistview = (ExpandableListView) parent;
explistview.expandGroup(groupPosition);
if ( getgroup != null) 
    questiongroup.setText (getgroup);


return view;
```

}

***This is the xml having the ExpandableListView:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is line 69 of `QuestionActivityMek`?

Comment: It's the expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout); line,

Comment: So, your **ExpandableListView** is named **footer_layout**?

Comment: Ah no lol, silly misstake by me. I added the layout for the ExpandableListView but it's still crashing and giving me the same error :/

Comment: It is not possible for `expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);` to directly generate a `NullPointerException`. Either you have the wrong stack trace, the wrong source code, or that is not line 69.

Answer (score 0):

Guess `R.id.footer_layout` is wrong, that must be the name of your footer or anyway wrong because it can not be found

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of two reasons.

1. Wrong type cast of a layout.

   expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
2. Second expListView is null. So try changing it like:

   if(expListView != null){
     expListView.addFooterView(btnAddMore);
   }

Answer (score 0):

Alright solved the problem by implementing following code

```
    //<<<<<Trying to add a button in the footer under the ExpandableListView>>>>>>
    final Button btnAddMore = new Button(this);
    btnAddMore.setText("continue");
    ExpandableListView explistview = getExpandableListView(); //<-- Used this methodcall instead
    explistview.addFooterView(btnAddMore);

    //<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>
    setListAdapter (listAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

i think your problem is this line

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) this.findViewById(R.id.footer_layout);
```

This line is not actually returning you the View but null. is `R.id.footer_layout` actually an ExplandableListView?

Comment: whats the -1 for? Was this help wrong or misplaced?